# Java. Tomcat. Сервер веб приложений не находит драйвер postgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, servlet, tomcat

Пытаюсь через сервлет (+ Tomcat) реализовать некоторые функции приложения по выводу списка из БД PostgreSQL.
Стек ошибок с основной **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver**.
Естественно в pom все зависимости записаны

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.20</version>
    </dependency>
```

Причем идея к базе подключается и через Main все работает, связь с базой есть. Как только хочу вывести через браузер- ошибка.

**Весь лог**

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
at repository.impl.AccountRepositoryImpl.(AccountRepositoryImpl.java:42)
at service.impl.AccountServiceImpl.(AccountServiceImpl.java:14)
at servlet.AccountServlet.doGet(AccountServlet.java:23)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bank
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
at repository.impl.AccountRepositoryImpl.getConnection(AccountRepositoryImpl.java:50)
at repository.impl.AccountRepositoryImpl.findAll(AccountRepositoryImpl.java:105)
at service.impl.AccountServiceImpl.findAll(AccountServiceImpl.java:27)
at controller.AccountController.findAll(AccountController.java:23)
at servlet.AccountServlet.doGet(AccountServlet.java:25)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Comment: Можете весь лог привести?

Comment: @EvgeniiVolkov  добавила

Comment: Как разворачиваете на tomcat? war или expanded war? В `WEB-INF/libs` war файла (ну или распакованого war файла) библиотека драйвера есть?

Comment: а код вот этого класса repository.impl.AccountRepositoryImpl? Может проблема описана здесь: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/load.html

Comment: @EvgeniiVolkov с этим классом проблем нет

Comment: @RomanKonoval библиотека postgresql лежит в external libraries, мне нужно jar этого драйвера перенести в lib непосредственно в C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-9.0.46\lib ?? и какой путь до драйвера тогда прописать?

Comment: java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315) at repository.impl.AccountRepositoryImpl.(AccountRepositoryImpl.java:42) at service.impl.AccountServiceImpl.(AccountServiceImpl.java:14) Это из вашего лога

Comment: @EvgeniiVolkov да я понимаю. но без tomcat, когда просто подключаю библиотеку через мейвен, (org.postgresql.Driver) все работает отлично. ПО всей видимости сейчас этот класс попадает в лог потому что tomcat не находит по этому пути драйвер.

Comment: @Sofia вам нужно определиться. Если вы хотите чтобы у вас подтягивалась версия через maven без необходимости конфигурировать томкат, то драйвер нужно ложить в war в WEB-INF/lib (не вручную, а мавеном) . Если же вы хотите конфигурировать библиотеку в томкате, то тогда то что в pom.xml прописано не имеет значение. Укажите версию томката (так как external libs такого понятия в новых версиях нет, что вы имеете ввиду, когда это пишете? куда вы сейчас и как ложите драйвер?) Ну и опять же вопросы, которые я задал выше про то, как разворачиваете приложение, попадает ли драйвер в war все еще актуальны.

Comment: @RomanKonoval  данный момент библиотека подгружена через Maven